# Combining the common parts of two MySQL queries results

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have 2 queries: one gives me a list of players who have open contract with club (no end date)

```
select ejl_players.id,ejl_players.surname ,ejl_club.short_name
from ejl_players
left join ejl_player_rights  r on (r.player_id =ejl_players.id and r.start_date=
(select max(start_date) from ejl_player_rights  where player_id=ejl_players.id  and end_date is null))
left join ejl_clubs on  ejl_club.id=r.club_id
where ejl_club.short_name is not null
```

Second gives me a list of players who haven't played since 2010

```
select s.player_id from ejl_play_stat s
left join ejl_protocols p on p.id=s.protocol_id
group by s.player_id
having max(pdate)<'2010-1-1')
```

I want to get the list of players who exist in both results, i.e. players who have open contract , but haven't played 2 years.
Second query gives back 10 000 records and when I tried to combine them like Jonny White recommended then my query didn't return (at least not in 30 min)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select ejl_players.id,ejl_players.surname ,ejl_club.short_name
from ejl_players
left join ejl_player_rights  r on (r.player_id =ejl_players.id and r.start_date=
(select max(start_date) from ejl_player_rights  where player_id=ejl_players.id  and end_date is null))
left join ejl_clubs on  ejl_club.id=r.club_id
where ejl_club.short_name is not null
and ejl_players.id IN (select s.player_id from ejl_play_stat s
left join ejl_protocols p on p.id=s.protocol_id
group by s.player_id
having max(pdate)<'2010-1-1')
```

Comment: I had similar conclusion, but unfortunately this query never returned (at least not after 30min).